# Is there any Mathematica functionality enabling its use for the blind?

Tags: front-end, user-interface

A colleague of mine has become blind as the result of a sudden medical misfortune. We want to help him to feel useful and active again. We, however, still cannot determine what can be done and to what extent, if anything.  He was a *Mathematica* user. To enable him to use it again, is there any *Mathematica* functionality enabling its use for the blind?

Comment: On most platforms, accessibility for the blind is mostly implemented by the operating system, and not by individual apps. Since _Mathematica_ tries to be platform independent, it may be a special case. I am not blind, but have poor eyesight. What accessibility aids I use all come from OS X, not _Mathematica_.  OS X provides voice over descriptions of screen displays and input by dictation for the blind. I do not use these features, myself.

Comment: Mathematica also provide some functions in `Accessibility`, such as `Speak` function can read out an expression, which can provide a little better results than system level function for MMA specific expressions.

Comment: Is reading out really helping a blind person? Wouldn't they want to "read" code like on an [Refreshable Braille Display](https://www.afb.org/ProdBrowseCatResults.asp?CatID=43)? So maybe somekind of `BrailleForm` would be a start next to `Speak`?

Comment: I am by no means an expert on these matters, but didn't Emacs (and possibly other general-purpose text editors) have rather good support for blind users, and possibly also modes for interacting with command-line Mathematica? It might be easier to go through command line than GUI, unless WRI has explicit support for this. Surely somebody at WRI would know the answer?

Comment: I thank all of you giving me advices here. Please go on, we need further ideas to pick up the one best fitting to the case at hand, even if not directly related to Mma. At the moment I understood that the first thing to try would be a vice system, as m_goldberg described, and later the Braill display, when my colleague will learn the alphabet.

Comment: may be interesting : http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/8544/

Comment: An [inspirational customer story](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/customer-stories/blind-optical-physicist-pursues-technical-career-with-the-aid-of-mathematica.html) about a blind physicist using *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I taught a blind student at our Uni a 1st year Maths module. We used his MacBook Air and he had a hardware device that rendered mac output as braille. We found that the key to communicating mathematics was a simplified form of LaTeX - which the student picked up very quickly. This, combined with Mathematica's LaTeX facility proved very successful.

Comment: Thank you, Peter. It is an interesting idea. Was your student successful in the end?

Comment: Yes thanks, nearly finished degree.

Answer (score 2):

My friend is using Mathematicа for quite a long time with the Jaws program. He is physicist and visually impaired. He uses it for scientific work. If there is still interest, he can share some tricks with the program.

Comment: You're referring to this?: https://www.freedomscientific.com/Products/Blindness/JAWS (I take it that it is Windows only?)

Comment: The answer is Yes, on both questions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a package *.m file is easier for him than notebook *.nb.  Stephen Hawking always has someone to assist him, so maybe we can give him some faculty or student intern to work with?

That way he can get his ideas out on paper, or record them on a tape cassette and depend on someone to help him transfer it to Mathematica and explain how that is working and how the output looks.  The student would in turn still get some math/physics experience.

I also like the suggestions made.  Braille and the command line interface worth exploring.  Text-to-Speech is personal choice, probably not as nice as having a student there to talk to.

Comment: Oh boy, I have bad news for you...

Comment: and what's that. It's not realistic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Hawking

Comment: so what if he's dead, doesn't mean my comparison is invalid